# Google Analytics - events as secondary dimension

Tags: google-analytics

In Universal Analytics, when you in web interface open a report (let's say New vs. Returning Users) and you use Event Label as a secondary dimension, it shows no data in the Conversions section, although there are conversions.
The conversion is URL based. Event is a click on a button, correctly implemented, in Events reports I can see events.
Does anyone have an idea, why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Event Label is a dimension that is only set on hits with type "event", whereas conversions based on URLs are coming from "pageview" hits, so they most likely have "(not set)" as Event Label dimension.

Comment: so it is not possible to see, which sessions, who had conversions, also had events during that session?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but you'll have to use segments for that. See <https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3124493?hl=en>